# Some theorem about block matrix determinants with symmetric inner matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I could do this problem with bruteforce but I think there must be some elegant theorem that helps to calculate the determinant with the block matrix (here having symmetric matrices inside) such as:

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 1 & 5 & 4 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\
4 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}I_{2,2} & S_{2,2,1} \\ 
S_{2,2,2} & I_{2,2}\end{pmatrix}$$

Actually, look this one

$$B=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
1 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
2 & 4 & 1 & 1 \\
4 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

and now I am thinking how I could use this one to speed up the calculation...determinant over this-kind-of-matrix-sum?

The problem is booringly stated as with Gaus method but I am interested to find some trick to calculate the determinante. My first idea was to do $4-3$ -row-minus and $1-2$ -row-minus (so getting some ones away but there must be some theorem to simplify the monotonous Gaussian elimination and determinant finding).

Page 741 [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.1020/materiaali/Mat-1_1020_juhani_pitkaranta__tkk_n_laaja_matematiikka_ii__2007_.pdf?state%3aCourseAdditionalMaterial=BrO0ABXcgAAAAAgAAGWVkaXRVc2VyV2FudHNUb0NoYW5nZUZpbGVzcgARamF2YS5sYW5nLkJvb2xlYW7NIHKA1Zz67gIAAVoABXZhbHVleHAAdxMAABBlZGl0RGlhbG9nSGlkZGVuc3EAfgAAAQ==).

**References by J.D. for further research**

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices
2. http://rscosan.com/documents/RCTM08_rcostas.pdf
3. http://mth.kcl.ac.uk/~jrs/gazette/blocks.pdf

Comment: Matrix $B$ is not symmetric.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: yes but the matrices inside are, I am trying to break this puzzle into parts and try to find some elegant way to solve this (without the bruteforce and actuallying doing everything one-by-one).

Comment: ...well I have solved this problem a long time ago with the knowledge that row-change means the parity thing with the minus so this is not really a homework, I am more here interested about a general theorem that deals with this kind of symmetric inner matrices. So do not provide the solution but try to address the general case.

Comment: Semi-relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices

Comment: and slide 7 of this: http://www.rscosan.com/documents/RCTM08_rcostas.pdf

Comment: If you know that matrix $B$ isn't symmetric, you shouldn't write "symmetric matrix such as $B$." Writing $B$ as a sum of symmetric matrices won't help unless you have some formula for $\det(X+Y)$ in terms of $\det X$ and $\det Y$. I think there isn't one, in general, and I doubt there's one even if you insist on $X$ and $Y$ being symmetric.

Comment: Also this http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~jrs/gazette/blocks.pdf

Comment: @J.D.: I gathered the references to the question (trying to keep things tidy) but you could easily make an answer with the details in comments, perhaps clarifying things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the matrices $S_{2,2,2}$ and $I_{2,2}$ commute it follows that $\det(A) = \det(I_{2,2}I_{2,2}-S_{2,2,1}S_{2,2,2})$.

Comment: ...why do the matrices $S_{2,2,2}$ and $I_{2,2}$ need to commute?

Comment: @hhh $\det(\begin{matrix}A&B\\C&D\end{matrix}) = \det(D)\det(A-BD^{-1}C)$ $= \det(A-BD^{-1}C)\det(D) = \det(AD - BD^{-1}CD)$. First equality is a property of determinants. Second equality by commutativity of scalars, and third equality is an identity of determinants under multiplication. If $C, D$ commute then $CD = DC$ and $BD^{-1}CD = BD^{-1}DC = BC.$ Hence $\det(\cdot) = \det(AD-BC)$. In your case, $A = D = I_{2,2}$ and $B = S_{2,2,1}$ and $C = S_{2,2,2}$.

Comment: I wish I could somehow copy-paste this LaTex to a separate answer to make it more visually-pleasing, @mods anyway? Also, I would like to move the references to an answer...